# Background processing in Clojure

Tags: clojure, jvm, background-process

I'm looking for a background processor in Clojure with features like Sidekiq in Ruby. Here is the list of the features I need:

- logging
- priority queue
- persistent queues (so jobs could be persisted between deployments)
- scheduled jobs
- Web UI admin panel would be great

I know immutant scheduling delivers the bare minimum, but as far as I understand, it doesn't provide persistence and priority. Is there anything like this provided by Clojure or Java ecosystem?

I'm new to Clojure/JVM and maybe it can offer an alternative that I might not even need this kind of tools altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anything under https://www.clojure-toolbox.com #Scheduling maybe ?

- [at-at](https://github.com/overtone/at-at)
- [Chime](https://github.com/jarohen/chime)
- [Cronj](https://github.com/zcaudate-archive/cronj)
- [Quartzite](http://clojurequartz.info/)

Comment: Thanks for the links.

Comment: AFAIU those are only schedulers, which is fine, but I'm looking for scheduler + persistent queue ideally with the ability to monitor through Web UI. I found [durable_queue](https://github.com/Factual/durable-queue) which covers the persistent queue requirement, but I was wondering is there something already existing which meets all the requirements?